# Custom Taxonomy as checkbox or dropdown

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, metabox, taxonomy

I have registered a custom tax to my CPT. On the edit screen the tax meta box appears with an autocomplete field.

Is it possible to display it as checkboxes or dropdown instead?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You probably did not set the 'hierarchical' argument to true in your register_taxonomy. This would mean that it defaults to false, which gives you a tag-like interface.

Add `'hierarchical' => true` to your register_taxonomy.

Comment: Oh yeah... Thanks! **BUT** Would it now possible to change it to checkbox or even select? I want to be able to put this as setting into my plugins settings.

Comment: Changing hierarchical to true should change the interface to checkboxes on your edit screen for the CPT.

Comment: Yes, it does – but I want to be able to switch between these options. I don't think that it is good practice to switch between hierarchal and not. It does not change ONLY the interface, am I right?

Comment: Well, hierarchical makes it... hierarchical :) You cannot switch between the 2 interfaces to my knowledge.

Comment: This solution doesn't create a checkbox or drop down menu.

Answer (score 23):

As of WP 3.7 (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14206) you can add this argument to register_taxonomy:

`'meta_box_cb' => 'post_categories_meta_box'`

to get the built-in checkbox category style metabox without having to make your taxonomy hierarchical.

Also you could instead provide your own callback function to create your own metabox (i.e. with a dropdown).

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I needed without having to make the taxonomy hierarchical. Thanks

Comment: The issue with this is that the non-hierarchical and hierarchical taxonomies have a different data structure that needs to be saved. For how to fix this issue see here https://gist.github.com/gschoppe/29ba81a1f676d7802cb8#file-cat-like-custom-taxonomy-php

Comment: This solution doesn't create a checkbox or drop down menu.

Comment: This is huge! Thank you... I never knew it existed

Comment: Where do I change the information as suggested by Justin Fowell? Sorry if this is very obvious for all, I am just learning.
Emily

Comment: In the register_taxonomy() call you have for your custom taxonomy. How are you setting up the taxonomy?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore? Set it like your example, but do not see a select field.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to change the term of existing plugin to checkbox you need to edit the existing register_taxonomy().

```
add_action( 'init', 'change_room_term_to_checkbox', 999);
function change_room_term_to_checkbox()
{
    $tax = get_taxonomy('roomtype');
    $tax->meta_box_cb = 'post_categories_meta_box';
    $tax->hierarchical = true;
}
```

'roomtype' is the name of term used on register_taxonomy('roomtype', array(.....